# My tmp folder in /sites/default/files/ doesnt auto clear in DRUPAL 7

Tags: linux, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and i'm having a problem with the tmp folder in /sites/default/files/ in my server.

I see that it is not automatically cleared and contains old files

I also see that it is set to nobody nobody.

And i want to know if  flushing all the caches clears the tmp folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Those files which weren't completely uploaded / downloaded to files folder will place in tmp folder.

You can simply delete those files. Moreover, you can build cron which can delete those unnecessary files in a period of time.